# Completing an incomplete JSON with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to have a js function that takes in a string format that might contain json in incomplete form. The function should return a complete json string.

For instance, I have a js string:

```
var incompleteJSON = '{ "title" : "Incomplete JSON made complete", "rows" : [ { "name" : "First Row", "value" : "First Value" }, { "name" : "Second Row", "value" : "Second"';

var completeJSON = makeCompleteJSON(incompleteJson);

// completeJSON should have the following:
// var completeJson =  '{ "title" : "Incomplete JSON made complete", "rows" : [ { "name" : "First Row", "value" : "First Value" }, { "name" : "Second Row", "value" : "Second" } ] }';
```

I was thinking to calculate from left to right the number of curly braces, the square brackets, single quotes, and double quotes while ignoring anything that is in between single quotes and double quotes. From there, it will then try to complete anything that is not matched.

Will this work?

Comment: Why not try and see for yourself?

Comment: take a look at some of the `extend` methods out there: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/, http://lodash.com/docs#assign

Comment: This is probably not a good idea. Unless you are getting the JSON from an external source you should try to fix the JSON generation instead.

Comment: Single quotes are irrelevant for JSON. Apart from that, your approach should work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A6pKb/1/ just try it, here is a small example

Comment: Thanks alot guys.. @JuanGarcia basically what I am trying to do is to read the first few bytes from a large JSON file and convert it into JSON.
Here's what I have come up so far: http://jsfiddle.net/setiawanh/wvDmC/3/ - still trying to figure out the problem of incomplete key value pair.

Comment: Hi all, managed to complete the functionality here: http://jsfiddle.net/setiawanh/wvDmC/